Is Bramha jnan compulsory to be a Guru?
Can deeksha be taken only from a Bramha jnani Guru?
Is it true that only Bramha jnanis can be called Gurus?
Are there any examples in scriptures where non Bramha jnanis became Gurus?

Duplicate of --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21084/4732

I) Your first question Can deeksha be taken only from a Bramha jnani Guru?
Bramha Jnānis are Jīvan Muktas [Tatva Bhodam: Ch-5, Page:14]. It is hard to find one!
II) Your second question Is it true that only Bramha jnanis can be called Gurus?
Answer is No.
Seeking a Guru depends on the need.

If I want to be become a Tantri/Mantravādi,  I seek a Guru who is
competent in tantra sāstra and has accomplished mantra siddhi.
On the other hand, if I want to become a sanyāsi, then I will never
approach a tantra guru rather than seek a sanyasi who will give me
upadesam.
Suppose I want learn Yoga, I will approach a Yoga teacher who is
skilled and knows yoga well, however he may not be aware of vedas or
puranas.

Kulārna Tantra(कुलार्णव तंत्र) [chapter-14] says the following regarding Guru accepting Sisya and Vice versa:
ज्ञानेन क्रियया वापि गुरु शिष्यं परीक्षयेत्‌ ।
संवत्सरं तदर्द्धं वा तदर्द्धं वा प्रयत्नतः ॥ १९ ॥ 

A Guru will test a sisya for at least 3, 6 or 12 months before
accepting him. ॥ 19 ॥

शिष्योऽपि लक्षणैरेतैः कुर्याद्‌ गुरुपरीक्षणम्‌ ।
आनन्दाद्यैर्जपस्तोत्रध्यानहोमार्चनादिषु ॥ २५ ॥
ज्ञानोपदेशसामर्थ्य मन्त्रसिद्धिमपीश्वरि ।
वेधकत्वं परिज्ञाय शिष्यो भूयान्न चान्यथा ॥ २६ ॥ 

Sisya has the right to gauge a guru through his proficiency in Japa,
Stotra, Dhyāna, Homa, Pūja and so on. After knowing his capacities for
transmission of knowledge, perfection in the science of Mantra,
ability to make subtle impact, one is to become his disciple.॥ 25-26 ॥ 

III) Your third and final question Are there any examples in scriptures where non Bramha jnānis became Gurus?

Maharishi Sāndīpani(महर्षि सान्दीपनि) was not Bramha jnāni, but he was Guru for Lord Krishna and Lord Balarāma [Harivamsa Purana Book-2 Ch-33], and he was known to have educated his disciples regarding all the Vedas, the art of drawing, astronomy, gandharva veda, medicine, training elephants and horses, and archery.

In Mahābhāratam [Book-1, Adi Parva Ch-133], Dronāchāryā (द्रोणाचार्य) was never considered as a Bramha jnāni, but he was Guru for Kuru Princes (pāndva and kauravās) teaching Danurveda (science of war).


Do you know any one whose Guru was a Bramha jnāni? As far as I know, Ādi Shankara was a Bramha jnāni. Maharishi Sukha Brahma (son of Vyāsa Muni) and Jada Bharata were Bramha jnanis.  Even King Janka (father of Seetha) was a Jnani.

Update: (based on comments received).
This update has been based on the comments "The true definition of Guru is the one who can guide towards that brahma-jnana" which implies that those offers brahma-jnana are true gurus and other are not! But Kulārna Tantra never say that those who give upadesam(उपदेशम्) to brahma jnāna (that leads to Jīvan Mukta and Moksha). According to Kulārnava Tantra(कुलार्णव तंत्र) [chapter-14], there are three kinds of Dīksha (दीक्षा/Initiation) as follows:
स्पर्शाख्या देवि दृकसंज्ञा मानसाख्या महेश्वरि ।
क्रियायासादिराहता देवा दीक्षा त्रिधा स्मृता ॥ ३४ ॥ 

Initiation by touch [Sparsa], Initiation by sight [Drksamjnā] and
Initiation by thought [Mānasa] all these three are done without
Rituals and without exertions.॥ 34 ॥

According to sloka [14.34], the difference among three kinds of Dīksha is explained by subsequent three slokas [14.35-37]:

यथा पक्षी स्वपक्षाभ्यां शिशन्‌ संवर्द्धयेच्छनैः ।
स्पर्शदीक्षोपदेशच्च तादृशाः कथितः प्रिये ॥ ३५ ॥
O My Beloved! Initiation and instruction by touch is likened to
the slow nourishing of its young by the bird with the warmth of its
wings. ॥ 35 ॥
स्वापत्यानि यथा मत्स्यो वीक्षणेनैव पोषयेत्‌ ।
दृग्भ्यां दीक्षोपदेशश्च तादृशः परमेश्वरि ॥ ३६ ॥
O Paramesvari! Initiation and instruction by sight is like
nourishing of its young by the fish through its seeing alone. ॥ 36 ॥
यथा कुर्मः स्वतनयान्‌ ध्यानमात्रेण पोषयेत्‌ ।
वेधदीक्षोपदेशश्च मानसः स्यात्‌ तथाविधः ॥ ३७ ॥
Initiation and instruction by thought is like the nourishing of
its young by the tortoise by only thinking. ॥ 37 ॥

While initiation the disciple receives not only Moola Mantra but also sakti(शक्ति) as given in the following sloka [14.38]:
शक्तिपातानुसारेण शिष्योनुग्रहमर्हति ।
यत्र शक्ति निपातता तत्र सिद्धिर्वजायते ॥ ३८ ॥

The disciple receives the Guru according to the impact of the Sakti
[Saktipāta]; where there is no impact of Sakti there is no fulfilment.॥ 38 ॥

Beware: Unless disciple receives guru blessings with enough impact of śaktipāta(शक्तिपात/transmission or conferring of spiritual energy upon one person by another), there is no siddhi (सिद्धि/fulfilment) is possible. Here guru should be a Siddha Guru (सिद्धिगुरु) the one who is competent and already attained siddhi known as Devata Vasyam(देवता वश्यम्) or Mantra siddhi(मंत्र सिद्धि) of the concerned Devata. Those are still considered as Gurus by the standards of Kulārnava Tantra, however they need not be Brahma-Jnani (ब्रह्मज्ञानी).
To corroborate this view, Kulārnava Tantra [Chapter-14] talks about Dīksha Procedure for Liberation subsequently in slokas [39-63]. The following two slokas [39-40] describes about seven kinds of Dīksha for liberation (मोक्ष), in other words Brahma-Jnanam (ब्रह्मज्ञानम्).
क्रियावर्णकला स्पर्शवागृहमानस संज्ञकाः ।
दीचा मोक्षप्रदा देवि सप्तधा परिकीर्त्तिताः ॥ ३६ ॥

समयाख्या विशेषा च साधिका पुत्रिकाहया । 
वेधका पूर्णसंज्ञा चाचार्या निर्वाणसन्ञिका ॥ ४० ॥ 

O Devi ! The Initiations giving Liberation are said to be of seven kinds:

Samayā (समया-दीक्षा/ aka क्रिया-दीक्षा): Initiation through ritual,
Sadhikā (साधिका-दीक्षा/aka वर्ण-दीक्षा): through letter,
Putrikā (पुत्रिका-दीक्षा/aka कला-दीक्षा): through special emanation [Kala],
Vedhakā (वेधका-दीक्षा/aka स्पर्श-दीक्षा): through touch,
Pūrnā (पूर्णा-दीक्षा/aka वाग्‌-दीक्षा): through speech,
Caryā (चर्चा-दीक्षा/aka दृङ्‌-दीक्षा): through sight, and
Nirvāna (निर्वाण-दीक्षा/aka मानस-दीक्षा): through thought.

1) The Slokas [41] describes Kriyā-dīskha (first of seven):

Ritualistic Initiation [क्रिया-दीक्षा/aka समया-दीक्षा] associated with
Kunda [fire-pit], Mandapa [canopy] and Kalasa [Jar], should be
performed by the Guru, O Devesi, adopting the prescribed means for the
purification of the body. ॥ 41 ॥

2) The Slokas [42-45] describe Varna-dīskha (second of seven):

Initiation by letters [वर्ण-दीक्षा/aka साधिका-दीक्षा] is threefold
depending on whether the letters are 42 or 50 or 62.  ॥ 42 ॥
O My Beloved ! Letters shall be placed on the body of the disciple and withdrawn in the reverse order, joining his consciousness to the Supreme Self.॥ 43 ॥
After withdrawl, the letters are to be laid again on the person of the disciple in the order of creation and as prescribed, so, too, shall be exercised the Consciousness. The state of Godhood full of delight is born in the child [of the Guru]. This is the Varnamayī dīksa which, O My Beloved, removes all bonds. ॥ 44-45॥

3) The Slokas [46-52] describe Kalā-dīskha (third of seven):

The Kalā-dīksa is also threefold to be done as prescribed. Beginning from the base of the feet up to the knee it is Nivrtti-Kalā; from the knee to the navel it is pratistha-Kalā; from navel to the neck it is vidyā-Kalā; from the neck to the forehead it is Sānti; from there to the head it is Santyāfita. This is the graded spread of Kalā-dīksa . ॥ 46-48॥


O My Beloved! Following the order of withdrawl, the knower of the sequence, joins from place to place up to the head. O KuleSani! This induces a divine feeling in the disciple. Or else with 38 or 50 Kalās in the order of Tattva-nyāsa and with the order of withdraw! and creation known from the mouth of the Guru one should center and impinge on the disciple. This gives birth to the state of Godhood and the meeting with the Yoginis and Viras. This is the Kalā-dīksa which destroys the bonds of the Pasus. ॥ 49-52॥

4) The Slokas [53] describe Sparsa-dīskha (fourth of seven):

Invoking Lord Siva in the hand, doing Japa of Mūlānga-mālinī, the Guru should touch the person of the disciple; this is the Sparsa-dīksa  [Initiation by touch]. ॥ 53॥

5) The Slokas [54] describe Vāg-dīskha (fifth of seven):

Securing the mind in the Truth, shall the Guru utter the body of Mantras which are expansions of the Supreme Truth; this is the Vāg-dīksa [Verbal Initiation]. ॥ 54॥

6) The Slokas [55] describe Drk-dīskha (sixth of seven):

Closing both the eyes and meditating upon the Supreme Truth, with a happy mind shall the Guru gaze well into the disciple, this is Drk-dīksa [Ocular initiation]. ॥ 55 ॥

7) The Slokas [56-63] describe Sāmbhavi-dīskha (seventh of seven):

When by the mere look or speech or touch of the Guru, there is an instantaneous knowledge, that is Sāmbhavi-dīksa.॥ 56 ॥
Mano-dīksa, it is said to be of two kinds : Tīvra and Tīvratara.
O Ambike ! Knowing the sixfold Adhvans one shall form in the body of the disciple the Bhuvana, Tattva, Kala, Varna, Pada and Mantra-from the knee, navel, heart, neck, palate to top of the head. ॥ 57-58 ॥
The wise shall then effect the Vedhas following the method received from the Guru. In a moment will the disciple in bonds get freed from them. This is intense, Tīvra-dīksa, O Kulesvari, yielding liberation. ॥ 59 ॥
O Devi ! Merely by remembrance on the part of the Guru, proficient in the Vedha, the disciple has his sin severed; this is the highly intense, the Tivratara-dīksa.॥ 60 ॥
O Simbhavi ! Released from external activity Sisya falls on the ground instantly; a godly state arises in him and he comes to know everything. Whatever is there at that moment of impact, he experiences it Beet but on waking up, O Isvari, he is unable to speak of that happiness. ॥ 61-62 ॥
Struck with such impact one verily is a Siva. He has no more birth, This is the Tīvratara-dīksa that releases from the bonds of birth and yields the very state of Siva. O Kulanāyike! 1 swear by You to this effect. ॥ 63 ॥

Conclusion:
Kulārna Tantra [Chapter-14] says in slokas [34] regarding three kinds of dīksa delivered without rituals and exertions as Aforementioned. These kinds of mantra dīksa(मन्त्र दीक्षा) are used for tantric upāsana(तन्तिक् उपासना) and tantra sādhana(तन्त्र​ साधना) particularly in the realm of Sākta religion. Such Gurus would be Siddha Gurus(सिद्ध गुरु) who should have already accomplished Devata-Vasyam(देवता-वश्यम्) or Mantra Siddhi(मन्त्र​ सिद्धि). These Gurus may not be Brahma-Jnanis (ब्रह्म ज्ञानि). However, it is hard to find a competent Siddha Guru rather there are plenty of charlatans, in the name of Gurus, moving around in the realm of Tantra!
Kulārna Tantra paves the way for dīksa methods for those who seek liberation (or to become Brahma-Jnani). There seven kinds of dīksas revealed by two slokas [39-40] which are Kriya, varna, kalā, sparsa, vāg, Drk and mānasa as discussed before. As discussed before, Slokas [41-63] explains about these seven kinds of dīksa in detail. Guru who is capable of giving any of these seven kinds of dīksas should be a Brahma-jnani (or Jivan Mukta) himself. It is harder to find a Jnana-Guru than a Siddha-Guru!
Good Luck!

Guru is term widely used. The true definition of Guru is the one who can guide towards that brahma-jnana.

@Kanthi, the question is general one and not as specific as you said. But Shankara refutes you and  please read  Manīshā Panchakam https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61558/a-question-about-guru-shishya-relation/61562#61562
